# Unable to run spock tests with maven intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, spock

I am trying to run spock tests with maven/intellij. But neither maven nor intellij are picking up test classes. It surely picks up the class but does not executed any test in the class.

Here is my spock test class

```
class SpaceAccessorServiceTest extends Specification {
SpaceLookUpService spaceLookUpService = Mock()
SpaceAccessorService accessorService = new SpaceAccessorService();

def gsProxy = Mock(GigaSpace)

def setup() {
    spaceLookUpService.getSpace(_ as String) << gsProxy
}

def 'should call readmultiple function on gigaspace proxy to get all objects from space for typename'() {
    given 'environment name'
    String envName = 'Grid-A'
    String dataType = 'data'
    String criteria = 'some-criteria'

    when 'call space accessor service to get all objects from space for typename'
    accessorService.getAllObjectsFromSpaceForTypeName(envName, dataType, criteria)

    then 'readMultiple method is invoked on gigapsace proxy'
    1 * gsProxy.readMultiple(_ as SQLQuery)
}
}
```

O/P from maven

```
     T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.ambuj.SpaceAccessorServiceTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.369 sec
There are no tests to run.

Results :
```

O/P at intellij console

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method should call readmultiple function on gigaspace proxy to get all objects from space for typename(com.ambuj.SpaceAccessorServiceTest) from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@5aaa6d82

at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
```

Things i have already checked

1) grovvy-all and spock libs added to classpath able to see them in dependencies tab in module settings

2) Surefire plugin configured correctly, since it picks up the file for testing

3) Test class generated in target/test-classes folder

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.class</include>
                    <include>**/*Spec.class</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Need help on what should am i missing here.

Comment: no, `class` should be fine

Comment: What version of junit are you using?

Comment: Is your folder set as a test folder under project structure? I often have to add then remove my tests there for intellij to find them again.

Comment: @HankD i am using junit 4

Comment: @MattBusche Yes folder is marked at test folder, i also tried placing the class in src/test/java, same results tests not executing

Comment: Looks like you're missing the ':' in 'given:', 'when:', 'then:'.

Comment: @Steinar...you are right, my bad should have been more careful

Comment: I was hoping for a more specific version of junit -- apparently before v. 4.11, spock had a problem with dependencies--had to add an exclusion on junit-dep until junit 4.11

Answer (score 0):

May be it's late but just wanted to highlight that @Steinar's comment solved my problem as well.

Being a first time Spock user, I also committed same mistake of not having labels `given:`, `when:` and `then:` in spec. Then stumbled upon this question to find Steinar's comment.